# “IndexError: too many indices for array” in array expanding

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

```
 ima = np.array(image)
 ima2 = ima[:,:,0]
 ima = np.insert(ima, 3, values=ima2, axis=2)
```

I'm encountering this error when I try to expand an `(224,224,3)` array into `(224,224,4)` in a vgg training code. But interestingly there is no error if only it is executed.

I don't understand what's wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess the error is thrown on the line that constructs `ima2`, not on the insertion. Most likely `ima` is not in the shape you expect it to be, maybe it's empty. Print `ima.shape` to debug.

Comment: I have tested it in a individual .py file and the result was fine. np.shape(ima2)=(224,224) and ima.shape()=(224,224,4)

Comment: So what is different in the training? What are you using for the training, how are you calling it, what methods of debugging do you have there?